# Texas Instruments Page/Register Convention - how to find the actual register address?

Tags: i2c, dac, texas-instruments

I am having troubles understanding TI datasheets regarding their DACs... I haven't felt so stupid for quite a while!

To make things as transparent as possible, here is a very literal question.

I am using Texas Instruments' DAC PCM5122. I would like to configure this DAC via I2C, and I'd like to program my MCU in C to configure it and stream data to it via I2S.

So, let's say I'd like to mute the left DAC channel... the way to do this is to set the RQML bit in the Page 0 / Register 3

This page/register convention is something I haven't faced before and it's awfully confusing to me!

The steps I would undertake, in achieving my goal using I2C interface, are:

1) I would firstly send the START condition;

2) followed by the chip address followed by a write-bit: i.e. 1001100[R/W] (binary);

3) followed by the register address;

4) followed by configuration data - just setting one bit, i.e. 00010000 (binary);

5) followed by the STOP condition.

Please feel free to correct me on any of the points above, if you should find them incorrect.

The question, of course, is what is the needed register address in this case?
Or, in general, how do I transform the given information (Page A / register B) into an actual address?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per page 75 in the datasheet:

> In any page, register 0 is the Page Select Register. The register value selects the Register Page from 0 to 255
>   for next read or write command.

So as far as I understand, the correct sequence to write register `R` on a page `P`, would be:
1) Write the number `P` into address `0` (using the steps you have described in the question) 
2) Write the desired value to the address `R` (using the steps you have described in the question)

As for example in your question - first write `0` into address `0`, then write the configuration data into address 3. 
I believe the first step can be skipped for subsequent reads/writes on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of IIC transactions. Each number is a transaction.

**For reading:**

1. WRITE page address to register 0.
2. WRITE register address.
3. READ register value.

**For writing:**

1. Write page address to register 0.
2. Write register address *and* data.

2 for writing is important. The data does not appear to be written if the address and data are sent in separate transactions.